# Auth0 get the asigned role using SDK @auth0/nextjs-auth0 v2.2.1

Tags: authorization, auth0, rbac

I would like to get the roles for a login user.
I would like to change the menu based on the user role so an admin user has additional menu options.

There is no issue with user authentication - this question is about authorisation.

In my API I have RBAC active and in the actions I have below defined within the login flow:

```
exports.onExecutePostLogin = async (event, api) => {
 const namespace = 'https://saintlySinners.co,uk';
 if (event.authorization) {
  api.idToken.setCustomClaim(`${namespace}/roles`,   event.authorization.roles);
  api.accessToken.setCustomClaim(`${namespace}/roles`, event.authorization.roles);
 }
};
```

I get the user details using

```
const { user } = useUser();
```

There is no role information returned.
How do I get the role information returned to AppMenu.tsx
user['https://saintlySinners.co,uk/roles']; returns undefined.